# Cannot find name 'ReadableStream' (simple-git, node)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

I've looked at all of the internets and cannot find a solution to this for my new project. I'm using the `simple-git` package and the type definition includes a couple references to `ReadableStream`. Typescript is raising an error ("cannot find name 'ReadableStream'") during transpilation. I've narrowed the issue down even farther, as shown below.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "./node_modules/.bin/tsc",
    "watch": "./node_modules/.bin/tsc --watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^10.7.1",
    "@types/yargs": "^11.1.1",
    "typescript": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "simple-git": "^1.96.0",
    "yargs": "^12.0.1"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "esnext"
    ],
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
  }
}
```

**./src/index.ts**

```
const s: ReadableStream = null;
```

...results in this error:

> > npm run build
>
> src/index.ts:6:10 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReadableStream'.
>
> 6 const s: ReadableStream= null;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

estus is right.  To the original point, it looks like a mistake in the `simple-git` type definitions.  You could file a bug.  In the meantime, writing `import ReadableStream = NodeJS.ReadableStream;` in a global declaration file should work around the problem.

Answer (score 3):

[Node global types are declared under `NodeJS` namespace](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/d42a3e4e16e57ff1fe5a18c300f568b6be4eb608/types/node/index.d.ts#L476). It should be:

```
const s: NodeJS.ReadableStream = null;
```